# MATLAB workspace in F# (view variables)

Tags: matlab, visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-code

Yeah, F# newbie here. Coming from MATLAB.

MATLAB workspace is window where I can see all my variables (and their types): 
[image]

And it is great, because I know what I can work with.

Is there something similar in Visual studio (code) for F# ?

Comment: You can do this while debugging in the full visual studio, not sure about code.  The isn't really an easy way on the interactive

Comment: I think [FsEye](http://www.swensensoftware.com/fseye) allows you to see and inspect variables when using F# Interactive.